# How can I call with Postman a RESTful API deployed with Gradio?

Tags: python, rest, postman, gradio

I'm following the basic Gradio interface from the [Gradio documentation](https://www.gradio.app/docs/interface):

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"

demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")

demo.launch()
```

The interface is:

[image]

I believe this deploys a RESTful API, since it says "Use via API" in the footer of the interface:

[image]

How can I call that RESTful API with Postman?

I tried:

[image]

but as the screenshot shows, I'm getting the error message:

```
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

The page that the "Use via API" points to indicate:

[image]

but I don't want to use the Gradio client.

---

Update: using the endpoint `http://localhost:7861/api/predict` seems to work better, but I am still trying to figure out what the name of the key is:

[image]

I tried to add a body but that doesn't work either:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on https://github.com/aiplaybookin/gradio-demo:

> Use [https://hoppscotch.io](https://hoppscotch.io/) or https://www.postman.com/
>
> - As the API is POST select POST
> - Paste the full URL https://locahost:7861/api/predict
> - Go to Body and Set the content type to `application/json`
> - Paste the input Payload in the body & convert your image to base64 using online tool (https://www.base64-image.de/) and paste it as value.

In my case:

[image]

JSON payload:

```
{"data": ["test"]}
```

Comment: hmm i'm getting `{
    "detail": "Not Found"
}`